# SEO in Blueprint CSS Framework

Tags: html, css, seo, blueprint-css

I'm creating a new layout for a site and I would prefer to use a grid-based css framework such as Blueprint (which is the only one I have experience with).  But does anyone know of a way I could place my main content above my navigation and sidebar in the html in order to improve SEO?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible using a grid framework as most of these rely on the relative locations of the individual source <div>s to achieve the grid.

Answer (score 1):

The 960 css framework ( http://960.gs/ ) lets you do that really easily using "pull_XX" and "push_XX" classes!